# how make services in symfony3

Tags: symfony, service, symfony3.x

i have this controller

```
namespace InicioBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use EntidadesBundle\Entity\Usuarios;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->session = new Session();
    }

   ..... 

        public function ver_rol($rol){
        if($this->sacarRol() === $rol){ 
                 return true;
             }else{
                 return false;
             }
    }

}
```

and in the **services.yml** , i got this:

```
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    app.rolSession:
        class: InicioBundle\Controller\DefaultController
        arguments: ["i dont know how get paramets"]
```

the problem is that it doesnt work, symfony return an error  FileLoaderLoadException, that the services.yml does not caontain valid YAML

Comment: Have you considered looking at the manual?  If you are using the actual Symfony framework then your posted code makes little sense.

Comment: @Cerad yes, but i want to do some thing diferent

Comment: This problem can be solved by reading the symfony documentation. Ether pass the session service to the constructor or use a setter. Both is described in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space before `parameters:` in your `services.yml` file, maybe remove that and your yaml should be valid.

Also if you are passing no arguments to constructor you can just delete `arguments: ["null"]`

One more thing, IIRC you need to add FQCN as class name, so `class: InicioBundle\Controller\Default` => `class: InicioBundle\Controller\DefaultController`

While we are at the subject, you can type hint Request in your action and use it to getSession() or maybe inject `@session` service to your controller

Comment: Hi!, thaks for help, do you know how i can send arguments?

Comment: @ANDRESFERNANDOMARTINEZVALEN in your argumenta array you can do `arguments: ['@session']` and the you have to add parameter to your conatructor, I suggest you read the documentation as someone suggested because this are pretty basic stuff and Symfony has best documentation